# GetPathByAction creates wrong query params for Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url, .net-core

I'm using the GetPathByAction method of the ASP.NET 5 LinkGenerator class to create links for my controller actions. This works well in general, but I just ran into a case where it creates bad query parameters. In this case I pass in the query parameters and use the current controller and action:

```
 GetPathByAction(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext, null, null, values);
```

`values` here is an object that has a few members, the problematic one being the `MyDict` member which is a `Dictionary<string,string>` with one key "foo" with the value "bar".

The query string when I call this endpoint is something like the following:

```
 /myEndpoint?page=1&myDict[foo]=bar
```

This is properly handled by the model binding and I get my object with the myDict dictionary and the proper values. When I now try to modify the page parameter and generate a new URL with GetPathByAction I get the following output from it:

```
/myEndpoint?page=2&myDict=[foo, bar]
```

The output is URL-encoded, I decoded it here to make this easier to read. To me this output seems to be simply wrong, it treats the dictionary as if it were an array (and even then this is not the way arrays are treated in model binding).

My expectation here was that the ASP.NET Url-generating functions would work the same way as the model binding. If ASP.NET can understand the parameter from a URL, it should be able to generate a valid URL from that parameter again.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug? Are there any other ways to generate URLs for a controller action with specific parameters that can handle Dictionary parameters?

Comment: Why do you want to pass a dictionary as query param? I can't see the problem that you want to solve.

Comment: @PeterCsala This would be nicer in the request body of a POST endpoint, but in this particular case I have to add this parameter to a GET enpoint, so it has to be in the query string. And the parameter is a dictionary with arbitrary keys, I can't change that.

Comment: @Fabian If any answers useful to you, you can accept it as answer. I can give them bounty.

Comment: @IvanYang Thank you for posting the bounty on my question. The answer by Peter Csala looks like a usable workaround for this issue, so I will accept this answer when the bounty is about to expire. I'm still wondering if there is a non-workaround solution, but I doubt it, it looks like a missing feature in that part of the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution to capture all parameters into a dictionary (which is supported out-of-the-box) is the following.

Let's suppose your GET method signature looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Get(int page, [FromQuery] Dictionary<string,string> mydict)
```

then if you call this endpoint like this:

```
/yourController?page=1&prop1=string1&prop2=string2&prop3=string3
```

- your `page` parameter will contain 1
- your `mydict` parameter will have 4 key-value pairs

  - `"page":"1"`
  - `"prop1":"string1"`
  - `"prop2":"string2"`
  - `"prop3":"string3"`

You can simple get rid of the extra key by calling the following:

```
if(mydict.ContainsKey(nameof(page))) mydict.Remove(nameof(page));
```

---

You can pass the dictionary to the `GetPathByAction` as an already formatted queryString:

```
var mydictAsQueryString = string.Join("&", mydict.Select(_ => $"{_.Key}={_.Value}"));
```

There are a couple of built-in helper classes (like `QueryHelpers`, `QueryBuilder`, `HttpUtility`, etc.) but I've found this snippet is quite simple and easy to use anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In this case MVC binding for collections does indeed seem slightly weird.

The bind provider for [dictionary types](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/DictionaryModelBinder.cs), extends the behaviour of binding a [simple collection](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ccfb12cf73b0285c981c70a2061312a837510f7b/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/CollectionModelBinder.cs#L271) like `List<KeyPair<K,V>>`. With each element bound by a special `KeyPair<K,V>` [binder](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ccfb12cf73b0285c981c70a2061312a837510f7b/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/KeyValuePairModelBinder.cs#L70). Before converting that collection to a dictionary via [Linq](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ccfb12cf73b0285c981c70a2061312a837510f7b/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/DictionaryModelBinder.cs#L239).

Then the dictionary binder will look for additional `prefix[Key]=Value` or `prefix.Key=Value` [values](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ccfb12cf73b0285c981c70a2061312a837510f7b/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/DictionaryModelBinder.cs#L215).